# How can I check backups on FTP server?

Tags: debian, backup, ftp

My company uses backup-manager to backup files to an another server.

I wish to check if tar.gz files on the FTP Server are not corrupted without downloading the file back to the original server to check.

How could I best accomplish this task?

Comment: Define `not corrupted`? And are you saying to want to check it *from* the FTP server, or *on* the FTP server. There's a big difference.

Comment: I dont know exactly. My company said that sometimes the backup weighs something like 1 megabyte or the backup is not decompresable. As I understood, backup-manager backup files in a folder, where there is files like database.tar.gz database.sql.gz and database.md5, and these files are send by ftp to an another server. There I need to check if the saves are ok.

Comment: `I dont know exactly`.. This doesn't bode well for your question. And now there's the question about how you plan to check if they're OK. Comparing checksums will *only* tell you if the files are the same, not whether they're actually any good. That can only be checked by trying to restore them and seeing how that goes.

Comment: If the files are the same, it should be good no ? They only way the back-up can be corrupted is during the ftp transfert no ? I don't think they can get corrupted during the creation of the tarball right ?

Comment: `If the files are the same, it should be good no?`.. Yes and no. If the source file isn't any good as far as a backup goes (can't be restored to the server, invalid for any reason), then you've just got two copies of a bad file. Corruption *can* occur during the transfer, but that's not what I'd be worried about.

Answer (score -2):

What you are after is an MD5 checksum. From the Debian Wiki:

> MD5 Sums are 32 byte character strings that are the result of running the md5sum program against a particular file. Since it is very hard to find two different files that results in same strings, MD5's can be used to determine that the file or iso you downloaded is a bit-for-bit copy of the remote file or iso.

https://wiki.debian.org/MD5

Comment: Thanks ! So I just need to do "md5sum -c backup.md5" ? Is it safe even if I have a very large files ?

Comment: It's specifically meant for large files!